# Swagger anonymousUser

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger

I have configured swagger to use login / password as followed:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Docket SwaggerApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("cms")
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext())).pathMapping("/")
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.ant("/**"))
                              .build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {

        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[3];
        authorizationScopes[0] = new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all");
        authorizationScopes[1] = new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all");
        authorizationScopes[2] = new AuthorizationScope("write", "write all");

        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("oauth2schema", authorizationScopes));
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration("app", "app-secret", "", "", "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER, "", " ");
    }

    private OAuth securitySchema() {
        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = new ArrayList<>();
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("read", "read all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("trust", "trust all"));
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("write", "access all"));

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        GrantType creGrant = new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant("http://localhost/swaggerAuth");

        grantTypes.add(creGrant);

        return new OAuth("oauth2schema", authorizationScopeList, grantTypes);
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Application")
                .version("1.0")
                .build();
    }
```

And this is my method for autorization:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/swaggerAuth", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_ATOM_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData) {
    String username = formData.get("username").get(0);
    String password = formData.get("password").get(0);
    final Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password)
    );
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username );
    return jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
}
```

When I login via Swagger all is fine. User gets authneticated and `Authentication` is set to `SecurityContextHolder`.

But with every next swagger request the user is `anonymousUser` and not the one I authenticated with.

What is wrong with my configuration?

EDIT:
The token I return from authorization controller is not beeing sent in swagger request headers...

Comment: Can you share your swagger.json ?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I don't have `swagger.json`. Code I've provided is my only configuration

Comment: Interesting... Do you get a UI similar to: http://petstore.swagger.io/ by any chance?

Comment: Exactly the same. It's available at `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`

Comment: In that case you should have a swagger doc, it could be JSON or YAML but everything you see there is driven by that swagger

Comment: Take a look at the page source, see if you can find it embedded there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in `authenticate()` method I was returning plain string. Instead I should return an object with `access_token` string field:

```
public class SwaggerAuthenticationResponse {

    private final String access_token;

    public SwaggerAuthenticationResponse(String access_token) {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }

    public String getAccess_token() {
        return this.access_token;
    }
}
```